# Thread.abort_on_exception raises anywhere?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

When using `Thread.abort_on_exception = true` any unhandled exception in a thread will be re-reaised in the main thread.

Now, it looks like it can be raised at any time which causes some issues making it really really hard to use.

Example:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require("logger")

Thread.abort_on_exception = true

Thread.new do
  raise(Exception)
end

Logger.new(STDOUT).info("FOO")

sleep
```

Running this code will sometimes print:

```
❯ ruby ruby_fail.rb
I, [2019-12-20T08:08:12.308942 #41552]  INFO -- : FOO
#<Thread:0x00007f90f21dd0c8@ruby_fail.rb:7 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby_fail.rb:8:in `block in <main>': Exception (Exception)
log writing failed. Exception
```

And the process keeps running.
However, sometimes it prints:

```
❯ ruby ruby_fail.rb
I, [2019-12-20T08:08:19.861318 #41971]  INFO -- : FOO
#<Thread:0x00007feb5012d048@ruby_fail.rb:7 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby_fail.rb:8:in `block in <main>': Exception (Exception)
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby_fail.rb:8:in `block in <main>': Exception (Exception)
```

And the process dies.

This seems to be a timing issue. The standard Ruby logger [rescues `Exception`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_6/lib/logger.rb#L700-L701), so if it's re-raised in the main thread, just as it's logging, the Logger will catch it and ignore it...

Is this a ruby bug? If not...using `Thread.abort_on_exception` seems pretty useless as it won't ever be predictable.

Using Ruby 2.6.5

Comment: "The standard Ruby logger rescues Exception, so if it's re-raised in the main thread, just as it's logging, the Logger will catch it and ignore it..." where did you get this assumption from? Just instantiating a Logger (as you're doing in your examples) would not catch any exceptions.

Comment: I'm not only instantiating it. I'm also calling `.info("FOO")` which actually logs. It rescues here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_6/lib/logger.rb#L700-L701